# Possessive/genitive case: "tradition of Holy Fathers" vs "Holy Fathers' tradition"

Tags: possessives, phrase-choice

Which one is generally preferred:

1. Image of Man in the tradition **of** the Holy Fathers.
2. Image of Man in the Holy Father**s'** tradition.

I would prefer the first, but is there a general rule or something?

Comment: Why *m* capital? Why no indefinite article? Am I missing something? Is it a title with flexible rules! :)

Comment: Because Man here means human being, so it does not need an article, e.g. `origins of man`, right? It may not need a capital M, but here it's used to emphasize his grandeur or something, as writing God with capital G...
Re

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I know is quite a popular thing. However, there are many exceptions.

> By default, **inanimate nouns** should normally get "of"

This having said, preferred is *Mike's temperature is rising* over *the temperature of Mike is rising.* On the other hand, *the age of the fossil* over *the fossil's age.*

Having this said, both are okay and convey the same message. As I find in sources, there's no single rule and the authors tend more to what looks natural.

[Good read is here](http://www.techques.com/question/32-30385/Apostrophe-s-vs-Of). Also, check the [selected answer here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/apostrophe-s-vs-of)

Comment: So, in my example, the second option is prefered, as Holy Fathers are not inanimate?
I understand that 'of' is preferable for inanimate things, but with animate, is it prefered not to use 'of'?

Comment: True as most references I found say. Remember, both are correct though. Because 'tradition', an inanimate noun, used 'of'! It's actually complicated - *the son of his father* or *father's son!*

Comment: I don't get it, who should be inanimate here, the tradition or the Holy fathers? =) I thought that it's only relevant here that 'Holy Fathers' are animate, what does 'tradition' has to do with it?

Comment: @Dmitri I edited and clarified further. Hope it's clear now. Kindly go through the links for detailed answer. I just put the crux.

Comment: Thanks, Maulik, I understand the general rule now. Can you state your opinion regarding my example, which option sounds more natural to you. I asked a few of my English-speaking freinds, and they all say the first option sounds more natural.

Comment: I go with them if I listen to my inner soul ;)